# Change window buffer color (to black) in i3wm

Tags: i3

I was wondering if there's a way to update the default window color when an image is buffering. Currently it's white.

For example, if I have a workspace open with just vscode, when I switch between workspaces there's a brief moment when the screen is white and I'd prefer the monitor be painted black while the image is buffering.

Sometime this issue also happens when moving windows around but it covers a smaller portion of the screen.

Comment: That is interesting, what system do you have? I have never seen that

Comment: I'm running it on a ubuntu 22.04. I have my resolution set super small so it might be a specific problem due to pixel resolution. My device is a ThinkPad workstation

Comment: It bothered me enough that I switched back to regular ubuntu for now. After I get through my current projects, I plan to switch over to Arch and try again

Comment: I think I got the root of the issue, read my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Just the color

There is a setting that may be precisely the answer to your question: change the buffer color to black ([Check the section in the manual](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#client_colors)) Particularly, for i3 version 4.21, the config would be this:

```
client.background #000000
```

#### Getting a Composer

If that does not solve the issue, perhaps you could address it from a different perspective. i3wm is a window manager with no "composing" capability. This, among other things, sometimes produces a loss of performance in some graphical tasks, such as problems with smooth scrolling on the browser, and/or flashing colors before showing the rendering of the desktop. (In your case is white.)

So you could obtain a compositor for i3wm. **Compton** is an option that seems popular among the community. I haven't tried myself, but the lack of compositor may be the root of your problem. Here there is ([an interesting related question](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3279/do-i-need-a-composite-manager-compton.1.html)) in i3wm FAQs. This is part of the answer:

> i3 depends on an external application for compositing and Compton is an excellent choice if you want to improve rendering quality or apply hardware-accelerated translucency effects.
>
> There are two issues I am aware of that affect stock compositing. One is screen tearing, which you may notice with animated effects such as Firefox's smooth scrolling. Another is a flash of partially rendered content when switching workspaces, or opening and closing windows. Using Compton should resolve those issues if it is configured correctly.

Comment: Wow, I was not expecting this level of research. Figured I just wouldn't use it. Thank you for this!